# Why is Angular's change detection inconsistent depending on the binding method?

Tags: angular, onchange

I've encountered an odd change detection behavior when using a Service. When I bind  **designElementService.selectedDesignElement** object reference to the **text-element-options** component's property, it doesn't detect any changes to the reference property.

If another component, for instance, changes it like so: **designElementService.selectedDesignElement=null**,  **text-element-options** still holds on to the previous reference and will not update the DOM.

Change detection will occur, however, if the referenced object's fields or properties change such as  **designElementService.selectedDesignElement.textBlock="Guru meditation detection error."**

As an experiment, I used a **@input** to bind **designElementService.selectedDesignElement** to **text-element-options** and it correctly detected the change. What's causing this change detection behavior? Are services first class participants in Angular's change detection?

```
<text-element-options
  *ngIf="
    this.designElementService.selectedDesignElement &&
    this.designElementService.selectedDesignElement.name === 'text'
  "
  #textElementOptions
  [selectedTextDesignElement]="
    this.designElementService.selectedDesignElement
  "
></text-element-options>
```

-

```
@Component({
  selector: "text-element-options",
  templateUrl: "./text-element-options.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./text-element-options.component.scss"]
})
export class TextElementOptionsComponent extends DesignElementOptionsComponent {
  Alignment = Alignment;

  alignment: Alignment = Alignment.left;
  decoration: Decoration = <Decoration>{};

  // this updates fine
  @Input() selectedTextDesignElement: TextDesignElement;

// this one doesn't
//  selectedTextDesignElement: TextDesignElement = this.designElementService.selectedDesignElement;

   // designElementService

  constructor(
    public designElementService: DesignElementService,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't detect any changes to its reference object"? input changes always trigger change detection, a service level object binding change of any kind (property or full reference) will not by itself, something else has to trigger it... but template bindings will update on the change detection cycle anyway which happens pretty frequently if not using onPush detection (mouse movements will trigger it)

Comment: I've updated my question. Let me know if it needs any more clarification.

Comment: sorry, i see what you're saying now, has nothing to do with change detection at all actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this actually has nothing to do with change detection (if you log change detection cycles, you'll see it's always running as expected), it's just javascript.

in your text element options component, you've assigned `selectedTextDesignElement` to the object currently referenced at `designElementService.selectedDesignElement`, not the current and future reference held by this service property.  So when you change that object reference on the service, the reference in components gets broken, they are still pointing at the original object.  but mutating that object clearly works since it's holding the same reference.  This is why you want to use rxjs subjects in a shared service model and not do things as you are currently.

Inputs work because that's a direct update from the parent.

Comment: Hmmm.  My Input isn't set to any property of the parent, but to the property of the service. I think I might be thoroughly confused by reference vs value. Is the input a reference and the component property a value?

Comment: you're thinking of it as though you're saying "point this component property at the same reference or value as whatever this service property is pointed at", but that's not what you're doing, you're doing "point this component property at the reference or value this service property is CURRENTLY pointed at", if you change that reference or value later, the link is broken, the component retains the original reference or value. I'd need to see how you're setting the input property in hte parent to comment further on why that works

Comment: In my first block of code, note designElementService.selectedDesignElement is assigned to the Input of the child component.  designElementService is just a property assigned to an injected service in the constructor arguments.

Comment: yea so you've assigned that input to be pointed at the service property, so whatever that service property is, will be fed to the input.  Inputs actually do change detect and update the way you'd expect, if you had instead, assigned the service property value to a parent component property, then fed that to the input, and then changed the service, property, you'd be breaking the link again so it wouldn't reflect..

Comment: OK. So I can just use the inputs instead of all that radioreactive stuff that makes your head wanna hurt?

Comment: you're gona have a very hard time developing an angular application if you don't get used to rxjs, it has a learning curve but it snowballs well,  You'll have bugs like this constantly. .. the moral of the story here is DONT do this haha, use rxjs / subjects when sharing values via service.. the only difference is you subscribe to a subject instead of assigning a value and call next on a subject instead of setting a value.

Comment: I reimplemented my service to use rxjs and the problem is solved. Thanks. I must say Angular wears no clothes. This sort of mechanism should be an integral part of the framework instead of delegating its usage to rxjs.

Comment: rxjs is an integral part of the framework. The framework itself depends on it heavily. But rxjs is an observer pattern lib, angular is an application framework that benefits greatly from a well done observer pattern lib. Doesn’t make sense for them to be built or maintained by the same team. Rxjs is useful beyond angular applications and angular does things rxjs has no concern with